# Rendering text on a page from the redux-store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a text input in React-Native component page and I send the input text to the store.

I am trying to render the input text on the page from the redux store but it will not display.

Below are my component and my redux store. Am I not calling the value correctly in my component with this.props.email?

COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text, StatusBar, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Counter extends Component {

  email(value) {
    
    
      this.props.email(value);
  }

  toggleCounterHandler() {}

  render() {
      
    return (
      <View>
        <View ><Text style={styles.welcometext}>{this.props.email}</Text></View>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                    style={styles.input} 
                    onChangeText = {(value) => this.props.email(value)} 
                    value={this.props.value}
                    />
                    </View>
        </View>
      
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      value: state.value
    };
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      email: (value) => dispatch({
          type: 'email',
          payload: value
        })
    }
  };
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

REDUX-STORE

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const counterReducer = (state = { email:'email' }, action) => {

  if (action.type === 'email') {
    return {
        
    
    email: action.payload,
      
    };
  }
  return state;
};

const store = createStore(counterReducer);

export default store;
```

Comment: did u try using 
` const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      value: state.email
    };
  }`

Comment: @AlyAbdElRahman I tried it but still no text will render in {this.props.email}

Comment: can you separate 
` state = { email:'email' }`  into variable and try in the redux

Comment: I tried and it still functions the same as before. The `value` in the text input is displaying 'email' from the initial state upon rendering the page...but nothing still rendering in {this.props.email}

Comment: @AlyAbdElRahman I got it to work. I converted state = { email:'email' } into a variable but also i used {this.props.value} instead of {this.props.email}

Comment: good to hear that :D